# How to save HTML "placeholder" attribute value into variable and alternate of "placeholder"

Tags: jsp, placeholder

I am displaying value in by using "**placeholder**" attribute in JSP and Bootstrap 4 like the following:
1)

```
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="nameTxt" value="nameTxt" type="text" inputmode="text"   placeholder="<%= di.getName()%>" Style="width: 320px">
```

2)

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="txtAddress" rows="5" id="addressTxt" inputmode="text" placeholder="<%= di.getAddress()%>" style="width: 320px"></textarea>
```

Java:

String name = request.getParameter("nameTxt");

String address =request.getParameter("txtAddress");

Question 1:
it is displays data correctly by using "**placeholder**" but i want to show in textbox(just like typing in textbox) rather in placeholder
How can i do it?

Question 2:
how can i store data in variable without changing the textbox(store placeholder value) in my class. Because it is able to store the value in variable only if i change the textbox value. If value exists in placeholder, it is unable to store in variable

Please give examples of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to show the name and address strings in the text box (as if it has been typed). And for question 2 you want to pass on the placeholder value.

So for Question 1, you just need to set the value, e.g.:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" name="nameTxt" value="nameTxt" type="text" inputmode="text" value ="<%= di.getName()%>"  placeholder="<%= di.getName()%>" Style="width: 320px">

<textarea class="form-control" name="txtAddress" rows="5" id="addressTxt" inputmode="text" placeholder="<%= di.getAddress()%>" style="width: 320px"><%= di.getAddress()%></textarea>
```

For Question 2, you can't submit the placeholder value through a form. However you can use hidden inputs that have the placeholder values to pass on the information e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="namePlaceholder" value="<%= di.getName()%>">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

- For textarea, you can simply insert the value between the tags

  <textarea class=""><%= di.getAddress()%></textarea>
- For <input>, you can use the value field

  <input type="text" value="<<%= di.getName()%>"></input>

Comment: Thank you so much. :)